# How owner can unsubscribe follower from the pubsub node

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack

We are using ejabberd SAAS.

Let me explain the scenario.

User A is an owner of the pub-sub “XYZ”.

User B is subscribed to the “XYZ” node.

In case of Ejabberd only User B has authority to unsubscribe himself from subscribed pub-sub node.

But in our use case, we want to unsubscribe User B forcefully from his pub-sub “XYZ”.

Is it possible?
Is there any SuperAdmin kind of privileges to achieve this? 
If possible then how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
This is possible pubsub owner can remove(unsubscribe) follower.
It's need to send stanza

`

```
<iq type='set'
    to='pubsub.domain'
    id='subman2'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner'>
    <subscriptions node='xyz'>
      <subscription jid='B@domain' subscription='none'/>
    </subscriptions>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

`